# Fifth ray amputation/resection - what does rehabilitation look like?

Tags: hand, recovery, fingers, amputation

I'm doing a bit of research for a story. A character loses their little finger including the metacarpal bone, so the left edge of the palm of the hand goes too. The wound is "healed" with magic, but that does not regrow any lost tissue, it just closes arteries, sutures tendons and muscles, and covers everything up with fresh skin. Consider this functionally equivalent to a [fifth-ray resection](http://www.oandplibrary.org/alp/images/chap07-01/b15.jpg).

The story deals more with the rehabilitation, as the character learns how to use the partial hand, and I've had trouble finding sources that don't deal exclusively with the operation itself. The info I need is estimations for how long it takes to regain full function, and what partial function looks like (discounting symptoms like phantom pain for now). I imagine that one is able to use that hand from the get-go when fully focused, given that the rest of the fingers are unharmed, but instinctive grabbing like catching a ball thrown at you would be a different story because the reflexes that one has learned over a lifetime are assuming a wider palm and another finger. But of course a better story would be based not on my intuition but on fact.

[This article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/10609597_The_Functional_Results_of_Ray_Amputation) talks about reduced strength. Are there any good sources that talk more about people's general experiences?